# Jmeter not connecting to AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jmeter

I am trying to perform some testing on my rds instance by using jmeter.
I have succesfully created a testplan with the help of [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) tutorial. when i execute the testplan, i get 100% error in summary report.

**Summary Report**
[image]

When i checked jmeter.log, it shows

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XxBkAq21_k3lj27uqd0GDxQ3kPJD37ey9Gy3aJsT6Ag/edit?usp=sharing

i think jmeter is not connecting with the rds instance, but i am not able to comprehend the reason.
i have copied the mysql-connector jar to the JMETER_HOME/lib
also, i have not edited jmeter.properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to restart JMeter after copying mysql-connector.jar to /lib folder of your JMeter installation. It can also be done on [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level via "Add directory or jar to classpath" input.
2. You need to provide appropriate "JDBC Driver Class" value in [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter) guide for end-to-end walkthrough.

Comment: i can share my testplan with you if u wish. my DB is running on amazon rds so u can also perform the testing from your side. pls provide ur email id , if it doesnt causes u trouble? i have tried that too, but not working (the blog u refferred)

Comment: upload your .jmx file somewhere (i.e. to google drive) so I could take a look

Comment: 1. Remove anterior spaces in `Database URL` and `JDBC Driver Class` in your JDBC Connection Configuration
2. Add `vartestdb` as "Variable Name" in `VM Expunging` request

Comment: ya, what u said solved the problem. i will now remove the file shared with you ? can i ? thanx :)

Comment: i have removed the link @Dm