# AWS RDS Instance is not connecting to Jmeter

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, jmeter, amazon-rds, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to connect my RDS instance to a Jmeter load test however no matter what I try, I keep getting this error message in the Results Tree:

> Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection to the host database-1.cqdkrfikhe1t.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com, named instance database-1 failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434. For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.)

I feel it may be a problem with my Database URL in JDBC Connection Configuration.

The picture below shows the summary report.

[image: This image shows the summary report as well]

I have mainly tried rewriting the Database URL multiple different ways but none of them seem to work. I have also tried removing and reinstalling the JDBC Drivers but that doesn't seem to work either. I have absolutely no idea what the problem could be. Could someone please help me out with this problem?

> Edit: When I change the Database URL I sometimes get this error
> message as well:
> Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
> Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target".
> ClientConnectionId:9b700d73-f3f0-4cf6-b3a4-607fa9827219)

Comment: "...and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434"

Comment: @MitchWheat How do I check if firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434? Sorry if this seems like a stupid question

Comment: can you ping [database-1.cqdkrfikhe1t.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com] from the machine where JMeter is running from?

Comment: of help?: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586790/jmeter-not-connecting-to-aws-rds

Comment: I don't know if AWS RDS can respond to pings. Even if it did, I wouldn't know how to do that. I also searched for people who had similar problems, but the solutions that worked for them, don't seem to work for me.

Comment: Would it be ok if I sent my test plan privately and you could possibly have a look at it. This is only an experiment so there is no confidential or personal data here.

Comment: post your connection string

Comment: @MitchWheat This is what I use for the database Url: jdbc:sqlserver://database-1.cqdkrfikhe1t.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1433;DatabaseName=database**;

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use port `1433`

Check out [Connecting to a DB instance running the Microsoft SQL Server database engine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html) article

[image]

So cross check the port number, VPC options, public accessibility, etc. with the values from the [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)

More information: [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter)

Comment: Hi. I am using port 1433, but I don't know why it's giving me a message about port 1434. I've also checked pretty much every website, I could find, that covers connecting a SQL Server to Jmeter. The thing is I've already tried it once before using Azure and it worked perfectly. But AWS doesn't seem to want to work.